# drupal 8 programmatically create node can only succeeded once

Tags: php, web, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I'v created a new module in Drupal 8, it is just a hello world example.
the code just like the following

```
class FirstController{
public function content(){
return array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => t('G\'day.............'),
    );

// <------I added the new node code here
}
}
```

and I added the following code to the content() function to create a node .
but I found that it can only create the node once, and after that no matter how many time I refresh the module page it won't be creating any more new node again.

```
use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use \Drupal\file\Entity\File;

// Create file object from remote URL.
$data = file_get_contents('https://www.drupal.org/files/druplicon.small_.png');
$file = file_save_data($data, 'public://druplicon.png', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

// Create node object with attached file.
$node = Node::create([
  'type'        => 'article',
  'title'       => 'Druplicon test',
  'field_image' => [
    'target_id' => $file->id(),
    'alt' => 'Hello world',
    'title' => 'Goodbye world'
  ],
]);
$node->save();
```

any thing I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot about caching :) Your output is just cached, and that's why your code is called only once (to be more precise, not once, but until cache is valid). Take a look here: [Render API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/group/theme_render/8.2.x#sec_caching) and here: [Cacheability of render arrays](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/render/arrays/cacheability).

To disable caching for current page request you may use the following code:

```
\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
```

So, your controller method may look like the following:

```
public function content() {

  // Create file object from remote URL.
  $data = file_get_contents('https://www.drupal.org/files/druplicon.small_.png');
  /** @var FileInterface $file */
  $file = file_save_data($data, 'public://druplicon.png', FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);

  // Create node object with attached file.
  $node = Node::create([
    'type'        => 'article',
    'title'       => 'Druplicon test',
    'field_image' => [
      'target_id' => $file->id(),
      'alt' => 'Hello world',
      'title' => 'Goodbye world'
    ],
  ]);
  $node->save();

  \Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();

  return array(
    '#markup' => 'Something ' . rand(),
  );
}
```

Comment: Actually, I was wrong :) `max-age` doesn't solve the issue for anonymous users with all caching enabled. In such a case you must call `\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();` to completely deny caching for current request. I changed my answer.